# getting authenticated user inside the configuration class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to authenticate users. I need to resolve which user has authenticated in my ApplicationConfiguration to provide the correct data,  but for some reason, the following code returns `null`:

```
 Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

---

**EDIT:**
I basically want to inject a service into a controller. (`PackagesBaseService`)

This service is abstract, so in my bean definition (In configuration class) I need to resolve if `PackagesBaseService` is an instance of `TablePackagesService` or `DeskPackagesService`. This is based on which user is authenticated (this requirement cannot be changed).

I understand I could just test the Authenticated user even in my controller and instantiate my service there, but I would like to avoid that.

---

I am able though to retrieve the Auth user using this same from anywhere else.

Why I can't use this from a configuration file? Does it have something with the order that the beans are loaded?

How can I solve this?

**Implementation:**

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public PackagesBaseService packagesBaseService()
{
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {

        if (authentication.getName() == env.getProperty("tableFactory.username")) {
            return new TablePackagesService();
        }

        if (authentication.getName() == env.getProperty("deskFactory.username")) {
            return new DeskPackagesService();
        }

        // thrown Exception
    }

    // thrown Exception

}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
PackagesBaseService packagesService;

public MultiPackagesResponse data(@RequestParam("fromId") int fromId)
{
    MultiPackagesResponse response = packagesService.getPackages(fromId);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? It only will deliver you an authentication if it's within a context which is invoked through a user action (e.g Http request). Can you post the whole class/method?

Comment: I want to inject a `PackagesBaseService` in my services: and I am using the authenticated user to decide if I should return a `TablePackagesService` or a `DeskPackagesService`.

Comment: @dur Thanks! Sure, that would explain why it does not work. =/ Thinking about a solution to my issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go with a factory to be able to use the user context. This COULD look like this:
Define a Factory bean:

```
@Service
public class PackageBaseServiceFactory {

    public final HashMap < String,
    PackageBaseService > packageBaseServiceCache = new HashMap();

    public PackageBaseService getPackageService() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            PackageBaseService packageBaseService = packageBaseServiceCache.get(authentication.getName());
            if (packageBaseService == null) {
                packageBaseService = initPackagesBaseService(authentication.getName());
            }
            return packageBaseService;
        }
    }

    private PackageBaseService initPackagesBaseService(String authenticationName) {
        PackageBaseService packageBaseService;
        if (authenticationName == env.getProperty("tableFactory.username")) {
            packageBaseService = new TablePackagesService();

        } else if (authenticationName == env.getProperty("deskFactory.username")) {
            packageBaseService = new DeskPackagesService();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); //or whatever you do
        }
        return packageBaseServiceCache.put(authenticationName, packageBaseService);
    }
}
```

and used it this way

```
@Autowired
PackageBaseServiceFactory packageBaseServiceFactory;

public MultiPackagesResponse data( @ RequestParam("fromId")int fromId) {
    MultiPackagesResponse response = packageBaseServiceFactory.getPackageService().getPackages(fromId);

    return response;
}
```